# Softlayer API--How does SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData know the time zone?

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I called `SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData`, it would return some values with a timestamp, like:

```
{
    'counter': 7591.0,
    'type': 'privateIn_net_octet',
    'dateTime': '2016-04-12T08: 00: 00+08: 00'
}
```

As it showed, `"dateTime"` will give a time zone, in this example, the time zone is`+8`, and I checked the server's time zone by shell command "date -R", it showed: `Tue, 03 May 2016 12:20:09 +0000`, the time zone is `+0`.

So how does it know which time zone it should use?

Answer (score 0):

The time zone depends on the configuration of your Softlayer user, you can edit the time zone by logging in Softlayer's portal and go https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile and change the time zone value.

Regards